# clang can't optimize away global variables used only in main()?

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, llvm, compiler-optimization

If I plug this c++ program into `clang` (version 3.7)

```
///*
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
//extern int printf(const unsigned char*, ...);


extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual() { }

struct A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
    uint32_t x;
    B(int x) : x(x) { }
    virtual void foo()
    {
        printf("This is a test %d\n", x);
    }
};
//*/
uint64_t thing = 0;
float other = 10.0f;
B b(12345);
int main()
{

    thing++;
    A* a = &b;
    other *= 3.14159f;
    a->foo();
}
```

And compile with `clang -emit-llvm main.cpp -fno-rtti -O3 -S`, then I get the following byte code:

```
; ModuleID = 'main.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p:32:32-f64:32:64-f80:32-n8:16:32-S128"
target triple = "i686-pc-linux-gnu"

%struct.B = type { %struct.A, i32 }
%struct.A = type { i32 (...)** }

$_ZN1B3fooEv = comdat any

$_ZTV1B = comdat any

@thing = global i64 0, align 8
@other = global float 1.000000e+01, align 4
@b = global %struct.B { %struct.A { i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8*], [3 x i8*]* @_ZTV1B, i64 0, i64 2) to i32 (...)**) }, i32 12345 }, align 4
@_ZTV1B = linkonce_odr unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8*] [i8* null, i8* null, i8* bitcast (void (%struct.B*)* @_ZN1B3fooEv to i8*)], comdat, align 4
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [19 x i8] c"This is a test %d\0A\00", align 1
@llvm.global_ctors = appending global [0 x { i32, void ()*, i8* }] zeroinitializer

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
define void @__cxa_pure_virtual() #0 {
entry:
  ret void
}

define i32 @main() #1 {
entry:
  %0 = load i64, i64* @thing, align 8, !tbaa !1
  %inc = add i64 %0, 1
  store i64 %inc, i64* @thing, align 8, !tbaa !1
  %1 = load float, float* @other, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %mul = fmul float %1, 0x400921FA00000000
  store float %mul, float* @other, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %vtable = load void (%struct.A*)**, void (%struct.A*)*** bitcast (%struct.B* @b to void (%struct.A*)***), align 4, !tbaa !7
  %2 = load void (%struct.A*)*, void (%struct.A*)** %vtable, align 4
  tail call void %2(%struct.A* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.B, %struct.B* @b, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define linkonce_odr void @_ZN1B3fooEv(%struct.B* nocapture readonly %this) unnamed_addr #2 comdat align 2 {
entry:
  %x = getelementptr inbounds %struct.B, %struct.B* %this, i32 0, i32 1
  %0 = load i32, i32* %x, align 4, !tbaa !9
  %call = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([19 x i8], [19 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %0)
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i32 @printf(i8* nocapture readonly, ...) #2

attributes #0 = { nounwind readnone "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="pentium4" "target-features"="+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="pentium4" "target-features"="+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #2 = { nounwind "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="pentium4" "target-features"="+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = !{!"clang version 3.7.1 "}
!1 = !{!2, !2, i64 0}
!2 = !{!"long long", !3, i64 0}
!3 = !{!"omnipotent char", !4, i64 0}
!4 = !{!"Simple C/C++ TBAA"}
!5 = !{!6, !6, i64 0}
!6 = !{!"float", !3, i64 0}
!7 = !{!8, !8, i64 0}
!8 = !{!"vtable pointer", !4, i64 0}
!9 = !{!10, !11, i64 4}
!10 = !{!"_ZTS1B", !11, i64 4}
!11 = !{!"int", !3, i64 0}
```

If you look at the main function, I have two variables that are useless.  Sure I increment one and I do some multiplication on another, but I never use the values in them ever.

But if you look at the output of the byte code, it looks like it is still doing the useless math.

Is it just me or is this a bug?

Comment: I doubt it's the compilers fault, more probable is that you did something wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those variables are variables in global scope. The compiler simply couldn't figure out whether or not those variables could be declared and referenced in other translation units.

I'd be surprised if any modern C++ compiler is sophisticated enough to figure out that execution flow could not escape this translation unit, in a defined manner, and thus it would be safe to optimize away unused global variables in this translation unit.

Comment: "that execution flow could not escape this translation unit" - what about other static initialization in other TUs? Constructors and functions used to init global and static variables in other TUs could run more code before `main()` starts. Thus, the variables must stay (unless link time optimization proves that they aren't used anywhere) but the writes in `main()` seem like good candidates to be removed, because even if any c-tor in other TUs started a thread, the access here isn't atomic, so it's UB.

Interesting.

Comment: LTO could catch this.

Comment: You might need GCC's `-fwhole-program` to promise that all the source code is here; but IDK how that deals with library code; I'm guessing it lets GCC assume library code doesn't use `extern float other;` to read the main program's global var.  LTO might not do that.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe that this is a bug, as your variables are globals.
Clang cannot remove this math as it can't know that any externally called function (like the printf function, in a different translation unit) doesn't declare `extern float other;` and somehow uses it.

Try writing:

```
int main()
{
    uint64_t thing = 0;
    float other = 10.0f;
    B b(12345);

    thing++;
    A* a = &b;
    other *= 3.14159f;
    a->foo();
}
```